# AlertDialog SetView Image size

Tags: java, android

I want to add an image in my alertdialog.
Android places it below text and it's oky but it adds some useless margin.
How ot replace it?

My view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rate"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My alert dialog:

```
 mAlertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true)
                .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rate_app_dialog, null))
                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle(R.string.exiting_the_application)
                .setMessage(R.string.rate_app_dialog) 
                .show();
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create a custom `DialogFragment` and use it. You can make a custom dialog fragment look any way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the following code any way you need. This is just an example of how you make and implement a custom `DialogFragment`.

He is the code I use. I find it quite flexible because you can create several similar dialogs for slightly different tasks. You will need to create a layout file - this gives you a great deal of flexibility on function and style.

My layout file is fragment_ok_cancel_dialog.

To satisfy your requirements just create your own layout file with all the elements in it you need (like your image).

In the Activity that calls the dialog you will need to implement the Listener.

```
implements OkCancelDialogFragment.OkCancelDialogListener
```

Another advantage is with my code you can change the title and the message to fit the needs of any Activity.

```
private void callMyDialog(){ 
    //Customize the title and message as needed
    String title = "This is my dialog title";
    String mess = "This is my dialog message";
    OkCancelDialogFragment dialog = OkCancelDialogFragment.newInstance(title, mess);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "OkCancelDialogFragment2");
}
```

Now you need to implement the dialog callback in the Activity that calls the `DialogFragment`.

```
@Override
public void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit) {
    if(submit){
        // Do something positive
    }
    else{
        // Do something negative
    }
}
```

Now the code for the DialogFragment:

```
public class OkCancelDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    Context context = null;

    private String title;
    private String message;
    private boolean submitData = false;

    private OkCancelDialogListener mListener;

    public OkCancelDialogFragment() {
    }

    public static OkCancelDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        OkCancelDialogFragment fragment = new OkCancelDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            title = getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE);
            message = getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveIntsanceState){

        context = getActivity();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ok_cancel_dialog, null, false);
        final TextView titleView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        final TextView messView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

        titleView.setText(title);
        messView.setText(message);

        builder.setView(rootView)
//                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button_dialog_title, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        submitData = true;
                        if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
                        mListener.onFinishOkCancelDialog(submitData);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        submitData = false;
                        if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
                        mListener.onFinishOkCancelDialog(submitData);
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OkCancelDialogListener {
        void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit);
    }

}
```

Please note that .setTitle(title) is valid for API 23 or higher (or maybe API 21 or higher?).